# discord.py: function wait until a specific date and time

Tags: python, datetime, discord, bots

i have a question again :)
i plan a bot that will give a message output to a channel after a user has tell the bot when.
i will show you the code and then i will tell you my problem:

```
import discord
import datetime
import time
import asyncio
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed

TOKEN = 'mytoken'

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
       return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user
    if message.author == client.user:
       return
    if message.content.startswith("!start"):
           await message.channel.send('Please type in the Enddate (TT.MM.JJ):')
           enddateinput = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
           enddate = enddateinput.content
           await message.channel.send('Please type in the Endtime (HH:MM):')
           endtimeinput = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
           endtime = endtimeinput.content

# *********************************************
# I dont know how to check the time with the subfunction time_check :(
# The optimal result is the function wait at this point until datetime.now(now) = enddate & endtime.
# and then i want the function to continue working.       
# *********************************************

           await message.channel.send('Enddate & Endtime reached.')
           await message.channel.send('Go on with the rest of the code :).')



async def time_check():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    while not client.is_closed():
        nowdate = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%y')
        nowtime = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M')       
        if (nowdate == enddate) and (nowtime == endtime):
           await asyncio.sleep(1)
# *********************************************
#           BACK TO FUNKTION
# *********************************************
        else:
           await asyncio.sleep(60)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

The problem is, i need time_check() only to check every minute the current time with endtime/enddate.
If the endtime and enddate reached, time_check() can stop working and go back to on_message() to continue working the funktion.

I absolutely don't know how to integrate this check_time () function.
I hope someone of you can help me.

Thank you guys.

Comment: instead of checking every minute if the end time had been reached, just calculate how many seconds are between the current time and the end time and wait that amount of seconds, that way it will be way more efficient and reduce the code length dramatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the functions you need to change, instead of checking every minute to see if the end time is reached I simply calculated the total seconds it will take to wait from the current time to the end time. I also added a check to see if the `end time is in the past` which is very important. In general I believe this is the best way to implement youre desired outcome.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user

    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith("!start"):
        # Get end date.
        await message.channel.send("Please type in the Enddate (DD.MM.YYYY):")
        enddateinput = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
        enddate = enddateinput.content
        # Get end time.
        await message.channel.send("Please type in the Endtime (HH:MM):")
        endtimeinput = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
        endtime = endtimeinput.content

        # Get the two datetime objects, current and endtime.
        endtime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            ".".join([enddate, endtime]), "%d.%m.%Y.%H:%M"
        )
        currtime_obj = datetime.datetime.now()

        if not (endtime_obj > currtime_obj):  # Check if end time is in the past.
            await message.channel.send("End time can not be in the past!")

        # Send the seconds to wait into the time check function
        time_to_wait = endtime_obj - currtime_obj  # The time delta (difference).
        await time_check(message, time_to_wait.total_seconds())


async def time_check(message_obj, secs_to_wait: float):
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    await asyncio.sleep(secs_to_wait)

    await message_obj.channel.send("Enddate & Endtime reached.")
    await message_obj.channel.send("Go on with the rest of the code :).")
```

Comment: thank you Raz Kissos. This solved my problem. By the way i have removed async def time_check(message_obj, secs_to_wait: float) and add followings into on_message:            time_to_wait = endtime_obj - currtime_obj , secs_to_wait = time_to_wait.total_seconds() , await asyncio.sleep(secs_to_wait). This work great, too.     

 Thank you for you great help.

Comment: Raz Kissos, i have one more little question. :)  How can i check if the User has used the right input format DD.MM.YYYY ?
`await message.channel.send('Please type in the Enddate (DD.MM.YYYY):')
           enddateinput = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30)
           enddate = enddateinput.content`

Comment: @loser09 you would have to check if the string length is exactly 10 characters long and contains 2 dots, one in the 2nd index and one in the 5th. then just check if all the other characters are numbers and if the date is incorrect im sure datetime will throw an error

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Enjoy your weekend.